# Counting number os BST

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Can someone explain me how we are actually counting the possible BST over here. I understand the basic part where we rely on the actual left tree and right subtree count to get total count. I am having a hard time understanding the loop.

```
public static int countTrees(int numKeys){
    if(numKeys<=1){
        return(1);
    }
    else{
        // there will be one value at the root, with whatever remains
        // on the left and right each forming their own subtrees.
        // Iterate through all the values that could be the root...
        int sum=0;
        int left,right,root;
        for(root=1;root<=numKeys;root++){
            left=countTrees(root-1);
            right=countTrees(numKeys-root);
            // number of possible trees with this root == left*right
            sum+=left*right;
        }
        return(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is not related to to binary search trees in particular but binary trees in general. The implementation uses an inductive argument to count the number of possible binary trees with `n`nodes.

The first case is the base case, where one onr no node can be possibly arranged into exactly one tree.

The second case counts the number of nodes by supposing that out of the `n` nodes, each node can be the root, which means that the remaining `n-1` nodes are to be distributed into the left and right subtrees, where all possible conbinations of distributions are recursively evaluated; note that apparently the nodes are distinguished, which means that isomorphic trees are counted multiple times.

After recursively evaluating the possible realizations for the left and right subtree, the resulting possibilites are multiplied to obtain the total number of possible realizations of the entire tree.

As an example, suppose you would like to evaluate the number of trees for `3` nodes, corresponding to the node set `{1,2,3}`. The number is larger than `1`
and each of these nodes can be the root, resulting in the loop doing 3 iterations as follows.

```
1 is the root, 2 remaining nodes to distribute.
2 is the root, 2 remaining nodes to distribute.
3 is the root, 2 remaining nodes to distribute.
```

The evaluations for `2` nodes will be the same, so we expand the call just for the first call. For `2` nodes, corresponding to the node set `{1,2}`. The number is larger than `1`, resulting the loop in doing 2 iterations as follows.

```
1 is the root, 1 remaining node to distribute.
2 is the root, 1 remaining node to distribute.
```

The evaulations for `1` node will be the same, namely there will be exactly `1` possibility.

```
1 is the root, 1 remaining node to distribute;
the 1 node can be in either the left or the right subtree,
resulting in 1 possiblity each, which is 2 possibilities in total.
```

This means that the result for a call for `2` nodes will be `2`.

Going back to the evaluation above, we obtain the following.

```
1 is the root, 2 remaining nodes to distribute;
   possibilites:
   2 in the left subtree, 0 in the right subtree;
       results in 4*1 = 4 possibilities.
   1 in the left subtree, 1 in the right subtree;
       results in 1*1 = 1 possibilities.
   0 in the left subtree, 2 in the right subtree;
       results in 1*4 = 4 possibilities.
```

Summing  up these possibilites, there are 4 + 1 + 4 = 9 possibilities to arrange a tree with `3` nodes as soon as the root is chosen; however, in total, there are `3` ways to chose the root, which gives the total result.

```
1 is the root, 2 remaining nodes to distribute;
    results in 9 possibilites.
2 is the root, 2 remaining nodes to distribute;
    results in 9 possibilites.
3 is the root, 2 remaining nodes to distribute;
    results in 9 possibilites.
```

If these are summed up, this is `9+9+9=27` possible trees in total.

Comment: Agree, the method above basically gives the no. of different binary trees can be formed with n nodes.